# What is a regular expression for matching a line of text that contains "Copyright"?

Tags: regex, text, filtering, deltawalker

I'm attempting to create a regular expression to use as a filter in DeltaWalker.  I want to identify the files that had code updated in a library that our project uses, but the library source files have all had a single line, `Copyright (c) 2008 - 2009` changed to `Copyright (c) 2008 - 2010`.  I'd like to ignore those lines because otherwise most files contain the same source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.*Copyright.*$
```

matches an entire line if it contains the word `Copyright`.

```
^(?:(?!Copyright).)*$
```

matches an entire line if it does *not* contain the word `Copyright`.

Which one you need to use depends on how filtering works in DeltaWalker.

EDIT: If you only want to match lines that follow the specific format you quoted, then you could use

```
^\s*Copyright\s*\(c\)\s*\d+\s*-\s*\d+\s*$
```

Comment: Thank you.  Curious, DeltaWalker's filtering doesn't seem to be working.  Not being familiar with regular expressions, I thought I'd test your solution with:  find . -exec grep -Hn '^.*Copyright.*$' {} \; in OS X's Terminal.  It works perfectly with grep, but not with DeltaWalker filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wanting the 2010 stuff, you can do this.

`^.*Copyright \(c\) 2008 - 2009.*$`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about DeltaWalker, but this regexp should will match both `"Copyright (c) 2008 - 2009"` and `"Copyright (c) 2008 - 2010"`

```
/Copyright \(c\) 200(8|9) - 20(09|10)/
```

You can try out different regular expressions easily with this site:

http://www.rubular.com